# Creating an infinite loop with an exception on C

Tags: c, loops, break

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

  int input, rev; //var to store number

  printf("\nEnter a number: "); //Ask user for a number
  scanf("%d", &input); //Store number

  if(input == 0){ //If number equal zero, terminate program
    return 0;
  }

  printf("The reversed number is: ");

  while(input != 0){  //Reversal code for any number
    rev = input % 10;
    printf("%d", rev);
    input /=10;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create an infinite loop where the program asks the user again for another number after it reverses the previously inputted number. It will keep on reversing the number until the user inputs zero. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Where did you even try what you want?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say Natasha

Comment: She meant that have you even tried to implement what you wanted to do? Don't ask a question unless previous research and testing has been done.

Comment: _"where the program asks the user again for another number after it reverses the previously inputted number"_...where is this attempt?

Comment: Please google "C loop" before asking a question here. There are literally hundreds of brilliant articles how for- and while-loops work in C. (Also always check the return value of scanf.)

Comment: I did try. I put a loop on the entire code to keep on running forever but that didn't work.

Comment: Did your loop have an exit condition? Do you know the keyword `break`?

Comment: I do know that. But how do you use that in a loop.

Comment: You cannot use `break` outside of a loop. `break` is used to break out of a loop.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
int val;

while (1) {

    printf("Enter the number to be reversed");
    scanf("%d", val);

    if (val == 0) {
        printf("exiting program...!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    // your code for reversing

}
```

Comment: You are not helping OP by teaching they to be lazy. Also please use indentation and explain things that are new to OP (`while`, `exit`). Also using `exit` to explain how to **break** a loop is not very good.

Comment: why someone down voted my code?? whats the problem in my code

Comment: @kay my code is small enough so that everone can understand.. and if we cant get out using exit(0) then  please tell me another way to do that

Comment: Before you edited your comment you used the word `break` in your sentence. That: `break` is exactly the how you should `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "do while loop" as in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int input, rev; //var to store number

  do
  {
      printf("\nEnter a number: "); //Ask user for a number
      scanf("%d", &input); //Store number

      printf("The reversed number is: ");

      rev = input % 10;
      printf("%d", rev);
      input /=10;
  }while(input != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not read the question properly.